# Spring MVC erro em realizar binding de checkboxes em uma lista de objetos

Tags: java, java-ee, spring, spring-mvc

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código em meu `.jsp`, no qual o objetivo é listar dinamicamente uma lista de passageiros por cliente.

```
<f:form id="service-item-form" action="${action}" modelAttribute="serviceItem" method="post">
   <ul id="list-of-passenger-service-item" class="list-cadastro">
      <c:choose>
         <c:when test="${empty customer.passenger}">
            <li>
               <b>O Cliente não possui passageiros vinculados.</b>
            </li>
         </c:when>
         <c:otherwise>
            <f:checkboxes items="${customer.passenger}" path="passenger" element="li" itemValue="id"/>
         </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
   </ul>
</f:form>
```

O *bind* é realizado no meu bean `OpenService.java` no atributo passenger, como mostrado abaixo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "open_service")
public class OpenService implements Serializable{

    //other attributes

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "service_passenger", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "service_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "passenger_id"))
    private List<Passenger> passenger;

   //Getter and Setter
}
```

Por fim ele dispara uma action com a seguinte assinatura:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-service/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addService(@ModelAttribute("serviceItem") OpenService openService, @PathVariable Long id) {

   //business rules

   return "redirect:/acme"

}
```

Mas o problema é que sempre dispara o erro abaixo de conversão, mas até onde eu sei nativamente o Spring MVC é capaz de realizar *bind* com objetos do tipo lista

> Field error in object 'serviceItem' on field 'passenger': rejected
>   value [7]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.serviceItem.passenger,typeMismatch.passenger,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [serviceItem.passenger,passenger]; arguments []; default message
>   [passenger]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of
>   type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property
>   'passenger'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
>   [br.com.joocebox.model.Passenger] for property 'passenger[0]': no
>   matching editors or conversion strategy found]

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, até hoje nunca vi bind com lista.
O que se faz é bind em um atributo e se adiciona esse atributo em uma lista e a manipula a seu bel prazer.

Tenta Fazer o bind em um Passenger passenger e adiciona esse objeto na lista e efetua as modificações necessárias.